# Adding a picture to background of pyqt5 interface

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to make the picture, which I placed it next of the text editor, appear in the background of the text editor and fill the window? Currently I can only show text editor and image side by side.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import 
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap 
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
class pencere(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self): #yapici fonksiyon
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        super().__init__() 
            
        self.setGeometry(100,50,1080,1080)   
        self.setWindowTitle("M content re-writer")
     
        self.texteditor()
        self.image()
        self.show()
        app.exec_()




    def texteditor(self):
      
        
        
       self.editor=QTextEdit(self)
        
       self.editor.resize(500,500) 
       self.editor.move(5,40)
       
       button=QPushButton("re-write",self)
       button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton" "{" "background-color : lightblue;" "}" "QPushButton::pressed" "{""background-color : red;"   "}")
                                           
       button.move(5,10)
       button.clicked.connect(self.function)
       
       
    def function(self):
        
        text=self.editor.toPlainText()    #editor'de yazan yaziyi al
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save file", "", "Text documents (*.txt);All files (*.*)")
        if text=="":
           print("none")
        else:
            
         with open(path, 'w') as murti:
                murti.write(text)
  
    def image(self):
           self.image=QLabel(self)
           self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap("yaratici.jpeg"))
           self.image.resize(900,500) 
           self.image.move(505,40)
pencere=pencere()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap 
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *


class Pencere(QWidget):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
        self.setGeometry(100,50,1080,1080)   
        self.setWindowTitle("M content re-writer")
        
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.texteditor()
        
        vbox2 = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        vbox2.addWidget(self.button, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        vbox2.addWidget(self.editor, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        vbox.addWidget(self.widget) 

    def texteditor(self):
        self.editor = QTextEdit()
        self.editor.resize(500, 200) 
        self.editor.move(5,40)
        self.button = QPushButton("re-write")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.function)
       
    def function(self):
        text = self.editor.toPlainText()             # editor'de yazan yaziyi al
#        path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save file", "", "Text documents (*.txt);All files (*.*)")
        if not text: # == "":
            print("none")
            return
#        else:
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
                        self, 
                        "Save file", 
                        "", 
                        "Text documents (*.txt);All files (*.*)") 
        if path:                        
            with open(path, 'w') as murti:
                murti.write(text)
  

qss = """
#widget {
    border-image: url(image.jpg) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
}
QPushButton {background-color : lightblue;}
QPushButton:hover:pressed {background-color: red;}
QPushButton:hover {background-color: #0ff;}

QTextEdit {
    background-image: url("rio.jpg");
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    color:red;
    font-size:24px;
    }

"""     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    demo = Pencere()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the background-image using a QStyleSheet.

```
self.editor.setStyleSheet('QTextEdit{background-image:url("yaratici.jpeg");}')
```

You may have to provide absolute path to the image file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give a try to :

```
stylesheet = """
    QWidget {
        background-image: url("your path:/"yaratici.jpeg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-position: center;
    }
"""
```

AND place where appropriate

```
self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```